# Why CUPS prints a blank page when the files contain a barcode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cups, printer, lp

Recently I installed a `Canon UFR2 Printer Driver for Linux` I own a iR1730 and I tryng to print a pdf file using `lp command`. I got to identify a "incompatibility" to read a code bar like this

```
00000.00000. 12000.102049 00229.690226 5 84660000238500
```

[image]

Is there a way to debug or find out the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

After many attemps I got to find what it was happening. I realized which differents barcode were being print. Thought it was decode barcode problem or something like that. But it was format page.

I installed the `printer_driver_cups_pdf` and printed through two methods.

```
Browser Preview - Control + P
LP command
```

Both with destination CUPS-PDF-Printer. Only `lp command` I realized that adjust it was at 55%, so to solve that:

`lp -o landscape -o fit-to-page -o media=A4 large.pdf`

I hope it help you guys